# How to create a singleton enumMap?

Tags: java, singleton, enum-map

I am looking for a method to create a singleton enumMap similar to Collections.singletonMap which is used for creating singleton maps.
The enumMap I want to create will contain only one element.

Comment: Why not just use `Collections.singletonMap`?

Comment: `EnumSet.of()`?

Comment: There is no one-liner for this, no better way than creating a new EnumMap and calling put on it, or using singletonMap instead of an EnumMap.

Comment: If it only has one element what exactly is the point of it?

Comment: It's API that I need to write test cases for. It takes an EnumMap. Few of the scenarios involve passing in a single value. I know I can work around it but was wondering if there is anything similar to Collections.singletonMap for EnumMap.